# Forward VM ports but disable any other network access

Tags: networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I'm trying to run a minecraft server on a VM. I would like my guest ports to allow access from the rest of the local network the host is on (and to my router so I may open the port to the web). **But I also want to block any other network access from the guest**, especially access to my host and other LAN devices. If the guest can still access the internet (but not my LAN) it's even better.

I tried :

- **NAT/NAT service** : forwarding works but can still access LAN

  - Tried to block using simplewall/Windows firewall, does not work. Still has access to LAN/internet (dns is not working tho). I tried to fully block with GlassWire, but then port forwarding doesn't work.
- **Bridged networking** : ports are opened, but I'm unable to block

  - Tried to put the guest in the DMZ, does not do anything. I think it's a bug with my shitty ISP' router
  - Tried to configure my router firewall to block any connection from my guest IP to any other device, does do anything either (the router asked for an inbound IP mask, set it to 0.0.0.0 or 255.255.255.0 but none of those work)

Other network configuration won't let me open the port

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to totally isolate the guest from the local network, but wish to allow it internet access and also to be accessible from the internet?

Comment: yes, I think bridged + dmz would have been the way to go but it seems broken on my router.

Comment: Questions: (1) What model is your router? Is its firmware updated and which version? (2) Are host & guest using Windows? (3) Are you using VMware/VirtualBox/Hyper-V?

Comment: The router is Orange Livebox 4 3.73.8 (up to date). Behind it's a Sercomm router. I don't have much more information unfortunately. I'm using Windows 10 on both hosted by VirtualBox (but can get VMWare if needed)

Comment: Is the host connected to the Sercomm router? Are all other devices also connected to the Sercomm router? Which exact model is the Sercomm router?

Comment: Yes, the host is directly connected. And yes, all other devices are connected to it. I also have very basic netgear switch in the back of my closet (unused but maybe useful?). I can't tell anything more on the router, it's juste written Sercomm then Designed by Orange (my ISP)

Comment: Btw, as an alternative if I can forward port but prevent any ther connection form my guest (internet/LAN) it would be another solution, internet access is not a requirement

Comment: You seem to have the Livebox 4. I don't understand what internet access is not a requirement - or what is the port-forwarding for? The netgear switch could be useful - which exact model?

Comment: Well my main requirement is port forwarding + no LAN access. Making internet accessible from my guest is not necessary

Comment: You can't have access from the internet to the VM without also having access from the VM to the internet. The netgear switch could be useful - which exact model?

Comment: The router I have is the TP-Link TL-SG1005D.

Comment: The TP-Link may support [VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN), but I can't find a useful manual for the thing. I suggest to connect it up and see if you can find the settings for making work [these instructions](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/788/). If they exist, we'll talk further. VLAN will let you isolate the VM in Bridged mode from the rest of the network.

Comment: OK, I'm going to take a look, although it maybe at my parent's, so I'll have to take a look. Still surprised its not possible inside VB to setup NAT without network access.

Comment: Other options are: (1) The Livebox supports a WiFi guest network without access to the rest of the network, if your computer has two adapters, ethernet and wifi.  (2) Hyper-V has a [NAT Virtual Switch](https://www.petri.com/using-nat-virtual-switch-hyper-v) that supports isolation, but that's much more complicated.

Comment: My livebox does support a guest network, so I could by a wifi adapter to connect my PC, great idea thank ! Seems OK in the article linked, but I have 0 experience with Hyper-V

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is to isolate a VM inside its own (sub)network.

The natural solution is to use 
[Virtual LAN (VLAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN),
but the Livebox router does not support this feature.
Another TP-Link TL-SG1005D switch is available, which might have
this feature ([link](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/788/)).

In the discussion above, up till now the best idea seems to be to add to the computer
a wireless network adapter, so as to connect the VM to the router via WiFi, since
the Livebox router does support WiFi guest separation.
The VM virtual network adapter must be in Bridged mode so it appears to the router
as a computer on the network.

Comment: Why would I want a bridged mode? Also wondering if my router is able to let me forward ports to guest network

Comment: Bridged mode separates the VM from your computer, making it a separate computer, so isolation will work better. I'm sure the Livebox can do port-forwarding in its home page, Network section, NAT / PAT tab. Don't use DMZ, it allows too much and exposes you to attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this not working for you, the simplest way is to set it up with a normal NAT config+port forwarding like you've got, and use outbound firewall rules, which are off by default. The main steps for this in windows look like this:

1. Open wf.msc
2. Navigate to Windows Defender Firewall Properties
3. Ensure "Outbound Connections" is set to "Block" (not the default)
4. Disable unneeded, pre-configured Outbound rules:

   - You probably only need the Core Networking rules, but some recommended rules to disable are:

     - File and Printer Sharing group
     - Remote Assistance group
     - Network Discovery group
5. Create "Allow" rules for minecraft server **(Windows may have done this already)**:

   - Click "New Outbound Rule" to start the wizard
   - Rule Type: Program
   - Program > This Program path > Browse to server.exe, or java.exe? The one making connections.
   - Action: Allow
   - Profile: All
   - Name: Allow-MyServer
   - Then repeat for Inbound.
6. [Optional] Block access to the minecraft server app from the LAN. **Note: Block rules take precedence.**

   - Create new Outbound rule
   - Type: custom
   - Program: server.exe
   - Protocol/Ports: Any/All
   - Scope > these Remote IP addresses > LAN Network

The Core Networking rule group should keep services like DNS and windows update happy, while still not allowing access to anything else.

If you want to go further than client rules, you can do the same thing on the host, or set up static routing on the host from the VM IP to your router's gateway (ISP IP, not internal)

Comment: I use linux as my guest, could do the same with iptables, but I'm assuming the worst, where the system running the server could be compromised